# Where is my friend traveling to?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

Over the weekend I met my old friend Wayne Machkeb, so we decided to go for a coffee and had a nice little chat. He was totally excited about a trip he was going to take but didn't want to tell me where.

After persisting for a while to tell me, he said: "Since you like puzzles so much, I'll give you some clues to where I've been in the past and you figure it out where I'm going".

This is what he gave me:

> - 48 6'.24; 11 31'.8; 1974
> - 53 31'.62; 9 58'.32; 1983
> - 45 31'.86; 9 12'.3; 1963
> - 45 31'.86; 9 12'.3; 1964
> - 45 2'.82; 7 39'.78; 1985
> - 41 23'.7; 2 9.3; 1992
> - 40 22'.8; -3 42'.6; 1956

And he said he is going to visit 3 cities on his trip giving me only these clues about the cities:

> - 2013
> - 1977
> - 1968

Any idea as to where he might be going?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate?  Now you've got me having _déjà vu_ — from where did you get this?

Comment: @can-ned_food not to my knowledge, it was just an idea I had, if there is something similar it is a coincidence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the next places will be -

> **Bayern München**, Germany - 2013
>  **Liverpool**, England - 1977
>  **Manchester Utd**, England - 1968

Reason

> The location co-ordinates seem to point at the cities/clubs who have won the **UEFA Champions League** in that year.
>
>  48.100067, 11.516889 - Obersendling, München, Germany $\rightarrow$ 1974.
>  40.366889,-3.700167 - Orcasur, 28041 Madrid, Spain $\rightarrow$ 1956
>
>  [Here's a complete list.](http://www.rsssf.com/ec/ec1stats.html)

Comment: Wow, that was fast :). I guess I made it to easy. Also I just noticed that I made a typo, it should have been 2012 not 2013 - resulting in a different city, but still based on the given data your answer is correct so I shall leave it so.